# mod-rewrite remove folder name from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using [OJS](http://pkp.sfu.ca/?q=ojs) and I have installed it inside a folder called "journals". I have created some journals there (for example "journal1", "journal2", etc).

Now I am getting paths like this: `www.example.com/journals/index.php/journal1`,
`www.example.com/journals/index.php/journal2`, etc.

What I want is to map `www.example.com/journals/index.php/journal1`
to looks like `www.example.com/index.php/journal1` (removing the journal part from URL).

I can't move OJS to root because I have some other files there.

Here is the `.htaccess` file which I am using currently (it's in "journals" folder and giving me a 500)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^journals
RewriteRule ^(.*) /journals/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also Here is the error.log

```
[Fri Oct 12 22:16:45 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Do you have an `index.php` file in your document root?

Comment: you mean project root?or site root?if project root-then yes,if site root-then no.

Comment: I meant, site-root, as in whether `http://www.example.com/index.php` actually resolved to an existing resource.

Comment: no.only index.html is there in site root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put those rules inside the htaccess file in your `/journals` directory, it's causing a rewrite loop. `$1` never starts with journals because you're inside the journals directory, thus the rule keeps getting applied.

You'll need to put something like this in your htaccess file in your *site-root*, the `/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/journals
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ /journals/index.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon-Its working fine.but now both site/journals/index.php/journal1 and site/index.php/journal1 are accessible.How Can I disable site/journals/index.php/journal1 part and only site/index.php/journal1