# mod-rewrite OJS How to remove folder name from url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, ojs

I have a problem.
My ojs installation is in a subfolder called /ojs, while in root folder there is a joomla site:

*www.my_web_site.com* (Joomla)
*www.my_web_site.com/ojs* (OJS)

Method described in topic 
[mod-rewrite remove folder name from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862809/mod-rewrite-remove-folder-name-from-url) 
doesn't work for me.

My OJS installation has only one issue, named "myissue"

So the issue homepage URL is:
*http://www.my_web_site.com/ojs/index.php/myissue*

I want this new homepage URL :
*http://www.my_web_site.com/myissue*

My .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ojs
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ index.php/index/admin$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My config.inc.php:

```
; The canonical URL to the OJS installation (excluding the trailing slash)
base_url = "http://www.my_web_site.com/ojs"

base_url[index] = http://www.my_web_site.com/ojs/
base_url[myJournal] = http://www.my_web_site.com/ojs/myissue/

restful_urls = On
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` **Just before Joomla routing rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^(myissue)/?$ /ojs/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava,
you mean in the Joomla's .htaccess?

Comment: Thanks, it works. :-) This rule redirects, but what do you suggest If I'd like to rewrite the URL (remove definitively the /ojs part)?

Comment: Hi anubhava, now my home page is no longer reachable (error 404). What do you suggest?

Comment: This is more than 3 year old answer. Has it stopped working all of sudden?

Comment: If an answer has been working for 3 years and suddenly stopped working then investigate what changed.